# What are your favorite resources to explain Cardano to people without a technical background?

Tags: resource-request

Many of us have been in this situation I suppose: You're with some friends/family and you get asked what exactly this "Cryptocurrencies", "Bitcoins" etc. are.

I'm looking for an easy to understand overview of what Cardano is. Something along the lines of what it can be used for, what the benefits and the risks are and what the goal of the project is.

Are there any such resources available? Videos, blog posts, anything that could be understood by someone who has no clue about the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommended videos

- [The philosophy of Cardano](https://youtu.be/o2fvwyPikuc?list=PLOMBocjNVI9i5TXFuzootbtJTPvTS3cIU) short version
- [The philosophy of Cardano](https://youtu.be/hIjMErpGij4?list=PLOMBocjNVI9i5TXFuzootbtJTPvTS3cIU) longer version
- [Charles Hoskinson's whiteboard video](https://youtu.be/Ja9D0kpksxw) for those who are not afraid of 50 mins of words like bandwidth, scaling, replication, etc. is a great intro to the challenges Cardano is designed to solve
- [How does bitcoin actually work](https://youtu.be/bBC-nXj3Ng4), the best explanation